# Do some debian builds not have lsb_release?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, lsb

A .deb package I am releasing expects that it can call lsb_release.  One customer using Debian 6.0.5 indicated that the lsb_release command (even in the terminal) produces a command not found error.  Is this standard or is there something wrong with his Debian build?

Answer (score 45):

There is an `lsb-release` package that supplies the `lsb_release` command.  This is separate from the `lsb`, `lsb-base`, and `lsb-core` packages.  None of the lsb packages are [essential](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8).  So if your package needs `lsb_release` it should specify that it depends on `lsb-release`.

Comment: Take care on proper naming: the package name `lsb-release` has a dash, but the `lsb_release` command has an underscore.

Answer (score 39):

Not all Debian builds have `lsb_release`. For example, even the official Ubuntu Docker image does not have `lsb_release`.

The alternative is to use `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: A new raspi to setup, time for my monthly visit to this question.